# C# & Excel: Value2 has no definition

Tags: c#, excel, visual-studio-2010

I needed a way to read an Excel file through c#.  I found an example https://coderwall.com/p/app3ya/read-excel-file-in-c

I created a standalone program to test it and it worked as I had expected.  I added the code as a subprogram into an existing program and encountered errors.

The first error, "Cannot implicitly convert type 'object' to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel._Worksheet. An explicit conversion exists."

The second error, "'Object' does not contain a definition for 'Value2'".

I fixed the first error with adding (Excel._Worksheet) to xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];

I can't figure out the second one on Value2 and need your help: "Error  98  'object' does not contain a definition for 'Value2' and no extension method 'Value2' accepting a first argument of type 'object' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Here's my code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Collections;ArrayList, ListBox, ComboBox, etc.
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using XView.Properties;
using System.Reflection;
using ZedGraph;
using System.IO;
using System.Management;
using System.Threading;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using Excel = Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel;



private void readExcelFile(ArrayList al)
    {
        string rowItems = string.Empty;

        //Create COM Objects. Create a COM object for everything that is referenced
        Excel.Application xlApp = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook xlWorkbook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open(@"W:\acad\x-pak\XPak setting_tool_charts.xlsx");
        Excel._Worksheet xlWorksheet = (Excel._Worksheet)xlWorkbook.Sheets[1];
        Excel.Range xlRange = xlWorksheet.UsedRange;

        int rowCount = xlRange.Rows.Count;
        int colCount = xlRange.Columns.Count;

        //iterate over the rows and columns and print to the console as it appears in the file - Excel is not zero based!!
        //---start at i = 4 since in Rick's Excel file, that's where the data begins!
        for (int i = 4; i <= rowCount; i++)
        {
            rowItems = string.Empty;

            for (int j = 1; j <= colCount; j++)
            {
                //new line
                if (j == 1)
                    Console.Write("\r\n");

                //write the value to the console
                if (xlRange.Cells[i, j] != null && xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2 != null)
                {
                    //Console.Write(xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString() + "\t");

                    if (j == 1) //new line
                        rowItems = xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString();
                    else
                        rowItems += "^" + xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2.ToString();
                }
            }
            al.Add(rowItems);
        }

        //cleanup
        GC.Collect();
        GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();

        //rule of thumb for releasing com objects:
        //  never use two dots, all COM objects must be referenced and released individually
        //  ex: [somthing].[something].[something] is bad

        //release com objects to fully kill excel process from running in the background
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlRange);
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorksheet);

        //close and release
        xlWorkbook.Close();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlWorkbook);

        //quit and release
        xlApp.Quit();
        Marshal.ReleaseComObject(xlApp);
    }
```

Comment: You're breaking the double dot rule. Using `xlRange.Cells[i, j].Value2` as an example, assign `xlRange.Cells[i, j]` to another `Excel.Range` object and then you can use the `Value2` property of that new object.

Comment: Your code works on my machine after adding a reference to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel. Please note that there are other tools that allows you to access Excel without interop and the associated issues.

Comment: @helrich, I appreciate your comment.  I can't figure out that either.  What I find odd is that the same code works fine in a standalone program but generates two errors when added as a subprogram.  I've checked my "using" and References and both the standalone and the subprogram are set the same.

Comment: Maybe you need to issue a "Rebuild Solution" command.

Comment: @Emmad Kareem, I'm not familiar with "Rebuild Solution" command. How is that done?

Comment: In Visual Studio, go to the "Build" menu, and choose the 2nd item from top "Rebuild Solution". Also, try to move your file to a local drive where you have complete access rights to. I assume you have Excel 2007 or above in your machine.

Comment: Thanks @Emmad, I didn't know about that. Unfortunately it did not clear the errors when I tried it.  It still doesn't like "Value2".  I'm on a local drive and using Excel 2010.  The Excel file that I am reading is on the network though.  Should I try and move it to a local drive?

Comment: Please check this and make sure you add all the references: http://books.google.ca/books?id=rgloOPCa3zoC&pg=PA722&lpg=PA722&dq=excel+2010+interop+c%23+value2&source=bl&ots=6QXxCdSyRO&sig=FqvFHrjS0CPixhI-kawWuLCnb_g&hl=en&sa=X&ei=taBrVJrJEsTsO-fFgZAM&ved=0CEwQ6AEwBw#v=onepage&q=excel%202010%20interop%20c%23%20value2&f=false

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/65171/discussion-between-bob-t-and-emmad-kareem).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The cause of this problem was the Target Framework! It was using .Net 3.5 because the main program was created in 2008.  This subprogram was added today and it assumes that "Embed Interop Types = true" (Property of Reference: Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel).

I went to the Project Properties and set the Target Framework to ".Net Framework 4 Client Profile". That generated 43 errors (can't remember the error name but indicated that maybe I needed to add a reference to Microsoft.CSharp.dll).  I added the Microsoft.CSharp reference and all the errors disappeared!

Comment: +1, Good one Bob, sorry I did not see your invitation earlier.

Comment: Thanks Emmad, when you said "
Please check this and make sure you add all the references", it made me check the differences between the standalone and the subprogram.

Answer (score 9):

I think it is relevant to Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel version. I have never previously used code block following ways to solve the same mistake. I think it will work for him.

```
   object _xVal;

    _xVal= ((Excel.Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[i, j]).Value2;
```

Comment: Can you add an explanation?

Answer (score 1):

I tried this same example tutorial and ran into the same issue. I resolved the issue in following method:

1. First, create a variable like this:

   `var sno = (Excel.Range)xlWorksheet.Cells[i,1];`
2. And then access the `Value2` property like this:

   `string serialno = sno.Value2.ToString();`

I am using .net framework 4.5

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me using .net 4.8 framework
(((Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Range)xlRange.Cells[row, 1]).Value2.ToString());